# Acids and Bases (Spectator Ions Identification)

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, everyday-chemistry

In an acid reaction with water, or other solvents, how do we know which atom(s) from a compound reacted with that solvent are the spectator ions? Are they the ones soluble in the solvent?
Is the way in determining this the same as the way we usually do it in a precipitation reaction?

Answer (score 2):

Spectator ions in any kind of reaction are those that do not take part in the interaction.

In precipitation reactions, they are those not forming the least soluble salt.

In acid-base reactions, they are those not manifesting in the given environment either acidic, either basic behaviours. Typically cations of alkali metal, or alkali earth metals, or anions of strong acids.

In redox reaction, they are those not being oxidized/reduced nor being produced by it.

For particular cases,  you must be familiar with chemistry of involved compounds.